# jQuery increase height by 10px without selecting element twice

Tags: jquery

I want to increase my selected elements height by 10px. Is there a better way without selecting the element twice.

E.g

```
$(this).height($(this).height()+10);
```

Is there some method in jquery which handles this that I have missed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(this).height("+=10");
```

Comment: this worked, is there any documentation on this? I could find anything on here http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: I can find this documented for `css` but not for `height`. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: From the docs, assuming that height() and css('height') were identical aside from the return value, it only made sense. Taken from this part of the api:
"The difference between .css('height') and .height() is that the latter returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .height() method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation."

Comment: is there a way to do this smoothly, like with transition?

Comment: How would you *animate* this growth?